# Which US visa do I need as a British citizen who had visited Iraq?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, us-visa-waiver-program

I want to confirm which exact US visa I need to apply for given my situation.

I'm a British citizen, but I've visited Iraq since 2011. I understand that I can't use an ESTA to visit the US, but I'm not sure which exact visa I need to apply to as the US website is not very clear.

Purpose of my US visit is tourism, so as a British citizen who has visited Iraq, do I need to apply for a B2 visa?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Purpose of my US visit is tourism, so as a British citizen who has visited Iraq, do I need to apply for a B2 visa?

Yes, this is the exact category you need