# Visiting Iraq after submitting B2 visa as a British citizen

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, us-visa-waiver-program

I have follow up questions to [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185554/78096) please.

I've already submitted B2 application and am awaiting an interview in July time. If I travel to Iraq before the interview, do I need to re-submit anything, or is it a matter of attending the scheduled interview?

Furthermore, my son (7 years old) has never been to Iraq, but he will travel with us to Iraq before our interview in July. Do I need to pre-emptively submit a B2 visa for him and bring him to our visa interview?

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to pre-emptively submit a B2 visa for him

Yes, they will not be eligible to VWP anymore and must get a visa

Comment: This is an important point (and I've already upvoted), but the answer does not address the question of the OP's own application.  Is any action necessary there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll get a B2 form submitted just in case then. Do I need to do anything if we travel to Iraq after submitting the form and before the visa interview?